# CircularLinkedList remove method not working

Tags: java, generics, generic-list, circular-list

I am experiencing a problem with my circularlinkedlist. it is a list, that is currently populated with Nodes, which each contains an object of my Person class.

The thing that im trying to do is:

Remove the node, 5 steps ahead of the start Node. It works fine, until i reach a point where my list only contains 1 Node. Then it gives me this error, when calling randomStart() and trying to print the list.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   cirkulærliste.CircularLinkedList.randomStart(CircularLinkedList.java:60)
>     at cirkulærliste.Test.main(Test.java:98)

if anyone could take a look at my CircularLinkedList class and my Test class, it would be nice. :)

```
public class CircularLinkedList<E extends Comparable<? super E>> {

    private Node<E> cursor;
    private Node<E> start;
    private int size = 0;

    public CircularLinkedList() {
        setCursor(null);
    }

    /**
     * tilføjer personer
     * @param p
     */
    public void addElement(E e) {
        Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(e, null);
        Node<E> tempNext = cursor;

        if(cursor == null){
            cursor = newNode;
            cursor.setNext(cursor);
            cursor.setPrev(cursor);
        } else if(size > 1){
            newNode.setPrev(cursor);
            newNode.setNext(cursor.getNext());
            cursor.getNext().setPrev(newNode);
            cursor.setNext(newNode);

        } else {
            newNode.setPrev(cursor);
            newNode.setNext(cursor);
            cursor.setPrev(newNode);
            cursor.setNext(newNode);
        }
        size++;
    }

    /**
     * udskriver personerne i den rækkefølge de står i listen
     */
    public void print() {
        Node<E> tempNode = start;
        while (!tempNode.getNext().equals(start)) {
            System.out.println(tempNode);
            tempNode = tempNode.getNext();
        }
        System.out.println(tempNode);
    }

    /**
     * en tilfældig person i den cirkulæreliste vælges som start i listen
     */
    public void randomStart() {
        int size = 1;
        Node<E> tempNode = cursor.getNext();
        // NPE occurs here
        while (!tempNode.getNext().equals(cursor.getNext())) {
            tempNode = tempNode.getNext();
            size++;
        }
        Random randomizer = new Random();
        int chosen = randomizer.nextInt(size);
        for (int i = 0; i <= chosen; i++) {
            tempNode = tempNode.getNext();
        }
        start = tempNode;
    }

    /**
     * fjerner den person fra listen der ligger 5 pladser fra start i listen. Personen der fjernes returneres.
     */
    public Node<E> remove() {
        Node<E> tmpNode = start;

        for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++){
            tmpNode = tmpNode.getNext();
        }

        Node<E> tmpNode2 = tmpNode.getNext();


        if(tmpNode.getNext().equals(start)){
            Node<E> tmp3 = start.getNext();
            tmpNode.setNext(start.getNext());
            start.getNext().setPrev(tmpNode);
            start = tmp3;

        } else {

        tmpNode.setNext(tmpNode.getNext().getNext());
        tmpNode.getNext().setPrev(tmpNode);
        tmpNode2.setNext(null);
        tmpNode2.setPrev(null);
        }

        return tmpNode2;

    }


    public void setCursor(Node<E> cursor) {
        this.cursor = cursor;
    }


    public Node<E> getCursor() {
        return cursor;
    }


    public void setStart(Node<E> start) {
        this.start = start;
    }


    public Node<E> getStart() {
        return start;
    }
}



package cirkulærliste;

public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CircularLinkedList<Person> list = new CircularLinkedList<Person>();


        list.addElement(new Person("Thomas", 1));
        list.addElement(new Person("Bjarne", 2));
        list.addElement(new Person("Camilla", 3));
        list.addElement(new Person("Bo", 4));
        list.addElement(new Person("Bobo", 5));
        list.addElement(new Person("Martin", 6));
        list.addElement(new Person("Søren", 7));
        list.addElement(new Person("Luller", 8));

        list.randomStart();

        System.out.println("START: " + list.getStart());
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
        list.print();
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");

        System.out.println("Deleting: " + list.remove());
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");

        list.randomStart();
        System.out.println("START: " + list.getStart());
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
        list.print();

        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");

        System.out.println("Deleting: " + list.remove());
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");

        list.randomStart();
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("START: " + list.getStart());
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
        list.print();

        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");

        System.out.println("Deleting: " + list.remove());
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");

        list.randomStart();
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("START: " + list.getStart());
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
        list.print();

        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");

        System.out.println("Deleting: " + list.remove());
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");

        list.randomStart();
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("START: " + list.getStart());
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
        list.print();

        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");

        System.out.println("Deleting: " + list.remove());
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");

        list.randomStart();
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("START: " + list.getStart());
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
        list.print();


        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");

        System.out.println("Deleting: " + list.remove());
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");

        list.randomStart();
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("START: " + list.getStart());
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
        list.print();


        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");

        System.out.println("Deleting: " + list.remove());
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");

        list.randomStart();
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("START: " + list.getStart());
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
        list.print();


    }

}
```

Comment: The line counts are probably different in your editor than when you paste the code sample here. Can you add a comment on the line where the error occurs?

Comment: while (!tempNode.getNext().equals(cursor.getNext()))

Comment: didnt think of that.. Im kinda new to this forum :)

Comment: you're completely right, totally misunderstood the problem

Comment: Can you add sources for Node class. Or that only me who's missing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken there's no reason to do this:

```
int size = 1;
Node<E> tempNode = cursor.getNext();
// NPE occurs here
while (!tempNode.getNext().equals(cursor.getNext())) {
    tempNode = tempNode.getNext();
    size++;
}
```

in randomStart().

You already increment a "size" int everytime the `addElement()` method is called. Just use `this.size` or just size after removing the above code.

**Edit:** <strike>I think your `remove()` method was more complex than it needed to be.</strike>

**Edit:** This now allows you to remove the final Node by making a special case of the size being equal to 1. It also returns the Node which has just been deleted.

```
public Node<E> remove() {
    Node<E> tmpNode = start;
    if (size > 1) {
        // Move five nodes from the start
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            tmpNode = tmpNode.getNext();

        // Move the start and cursor nodes if
        // they are about to be removed.
        if (tmpNode.equals(start))
            start = start.getNext();
        if (tmpNode.equals(cursor))
            cursor = cursor.getNext();

        // Remove the fifth node
        Node<E> next = tmpNode.getNext();
        Node<E> prev = tmpNode.getPrev();
        prev.setNext(next);
        next.setPrev(prev);

        size--;
    } else if (size == 1) {
        start = null;
        cursor = null;

        size--;
    }
    return tmpNode;
}
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Yes, i think the null values occurs after use og the remove method, but i just can't seem to see where exactly. Any further help would be appreciated

Comment: I've updated my answer! I believe this is what you wanted the remove() method to do?

Comment: @ThomasTeilmann Have you tried stepping through the calls to remove() in a debugger?

Comment: Sorry guys, i needed to go to bed. Im up again now, and will let you know if this works.

Comment: Ive tried implementing your remove method, but it seems to have it's flaws too. It is like, sometimes, it doesn't remove the Node it returns. I will have a look at that in a minut. Have to make coffee

Comment: I fixed it.. It seems that this remove method was returning the Node, BEFORE, the one that actually got removed.. Now it is fine.

I just have one more question though: how do i get it to remove the last element, when there is only 1 Node left in the list?

Comment: @ThomasTeilmann Ahh, I should've realised what it was supposed to return. If you want to be able to remove the last element then you'd need to create a special case for size being equal to 1 to set the start and cursor to null. I've updated my answer to reflect this.